# Is the a way to create a batch file to remove folders but keep all the files?

Tags: file, batch-file, directory

Ive been trying create a batch file that scrubs all drivers and other elements of a computer to a USB flash drive. The batch file is functional but it gathers the data in a ridiculous amount of folders with subdirectories which makes the data useless.

Ive been trying to find a way to collapse or remove the folders and put all the files into one folder.

I found that this command:

```
for /r "source" %f in (*) do @copy "%f" "target"
```

works but for some reason wont operate in any batch file.

Does anyone know away to do this? Either move the files to one folder or copy then delete.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What's the way you're going to handle files with similar names?

Comment: havent got a clue, batch files are fairly new to me so im trying it one step at a time, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `%` variables in a batch file, you need double-`%`:

```
for /r "source" %%f in (*) do @copy "%%f" "target"
```

But you may want to consider what's going to happen to the two files `dir1/file.txt` and `dir2\file.txt` when you try to put them in the same directory.

By the way, why have you not thought about using `xcopy`?

Comment: I tried that but it still wont function, im trying for /r "F:\Scrub\32bit\First" %%f in (*) do @copy "%%f" "F:\Scrub\32bit\Second" . I was planning to find a away to append them (file.txt and file (1).txt). Honestly I didnt cross my mind, how would it be capable of doing that?

Comment: It would be a good idea to use copy `"%%~f"` instead of `"%%f"`, as this is also safe with spaces in filenames

Comment: so you would suggest using 
copy /r "F:\Scrub\32bit\First" %%f in (*) do @copy "%%~f" "F:\Scrub\32bit\Second"
i have tried this but it wont launch in a batch file. am i missing something!?!